# IB Python API Can't Find Security Definition

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance, interactive-brokers

I have the following code which is attempting to pull historical bar data using IBKR Python API.  I made sure TWS workstation was running and that sockets/ActiveX was enabled with the correct port for paper trading.  I also verified that I can pull up a chart for EUR.USD within TWS and that all market data sources are showing as "connected".  The code should be able to pull 5 minute bar data for EUR.USD but I am getting an error in the output:

Code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import threading
import time


class TradingApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)
        
    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print("HistoricalData. ReqId:", reqId, "BarData.", bar)
        

def websocket_con():
    app.run()
    
app = TradingApp()      
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=1)

con_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_con, daemon=True)
con_thread.start()
time.sleep(1) 


contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "EUR.USD"
contract.secType = "CASH"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.exchange = "IDEALPRO"

app.reqHistoricalData(reqId=1, 
                      contract=contract,
                      endDateTime='',
                      durationStr='3 M',
                      barSizeSetting='5 mins',
                      whatToShow='MIDPOINT',
                      useRTH=0,
                      formatDate=1,
                      keepUpToDate=0,
                      chartOptions=[])   
time.sleep(5)
```

The output is as follows:

```
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:cashhmds
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefil
ERROR 1 200 No security definition has been found for the request
```

How do I resolve this error and pull the bar data?

Comment: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/basic_contracts.html#cash  `contract.symbol = "EUR"`

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

change this line
contract.symbol = "EUR"